# Datetime won't save using correct time zone

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

Ok so I've been trying to sort this out all day and I've not made a single bit of progress.

I have a set up a site on Salesforce as a web service endpoint. A client's system sends an HTTP request with a few bits of information as GET parameters and then our salesforce updates a record.

I noticed that the date was saving an hour later than it was and I cannot get it to save correctly no matter what I have tried.

The Custom_Object__c has two datetime fields, one which is set to Datetime.now() when the record is created, we'll call that Datetime_1__c. This one saves correctly. The other field, Datetime_2__c is set when the HTTP request comes through with a date string in the GET parameters. The date string is +01:00 time zone, and requires a bit of reformatting before converting.

The apex code is below:

```
 String dtStr = g_datetime.substring(0, 19).replaceAll('T', ' ') + '+01:00';
 System.debug('Date/Time string to save:' + dtStr);
 Datetime dt = Datetime.valueOf(dtStr);
 System.debug('Date/Time to save:' + String.valueOf(dt));
 relatedRecord.Receipt_Received_At__c = dt;
```

The debug log shows these two entries:

```
13:58:07.038 (38233077)|USER_DEBUG|[49]|DEBUG|Date/Time string to save:2014-06-19 14:44:00+01:00
13:58:07.038 (38416001)|USER_DEBUG|[51]|DEBUG|Date/Time to save:2014-06-19 14:44:00
```

But when I go on the record detail page, the time shows as 15:44. My user time zone is BST (+01:00) and so is the company default, but when I set these to any other time zones it STILL puts the date an hour ahead.

What do I need to add or remove from my code to make this appear correctly?

Comment: SF always saves date time data to the database in GMT or what's now referred to as UTC and then converts it to the local time zone when it's re-displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DateTime.valueOf(string)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_valueOf) method has the following Usage note in the docs:

> The specified string should use the standard date format “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss” in the local time zone.

It is ignoring the +1 UTC offset.

If I run the following as anonymous Apex:

```
String dtStr = '2014-06-19 14:44:00+01:00';
System.debug('Date/Time string to save:' + dtStr);
Datetime dt = Datetime.valueOf(dtStr);
System.debug('Date/Time to save:' + String.valueOf(dt));
System.debug('hour(): ' + dt.hour());
System.debug('hourGmt(): ' + dt.hourGmt());
```

I get:

> 12:33:15.258 (258899135)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|Date/Time string to save:2014-06-19 14:44:00+01:00
>   12:33:15.259 (259067845)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|Date/Time to save:2014-06-19 14:44:00
>   12:33:15.259 (259158685)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|hour(): 14
>   12:33:15.259 (259232093)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|hourGmt(): 21

In this particular instance my Salesforce users timezone is set to (GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Tijuana).

As an alternative, try formatting the input string in the IS0 8601 format. You can then convert it to a UTC DateTime with:

```
String dtStr = '2014-06-19T14:44:00.000Z';
System.debug('Date/Time string to save:' + dtStr);
Datetime dt = (DateTime)json.deserialize('"' + dtStr + '"', datetime.class);
System.debug('Date/Time to save:' + String.valueOf(dt));
System.debug('hour(): ' + dt.hour());
System.debug('hourGmt(): ' + dt.hourGmt());
```

Which gives:

> 12:43:52.272 (272399372)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|Date/Time string to save:2014-06-19T14:44:00.000Z
>   12:43:52.273 (273942997)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|Date/Time to save:2014-06-19 07:44:00
>   12:43:52.274 (274047548)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|hour(): 7
>   12:43:52.274 (274124974)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|hourGmt(): 7

You can encode the timezone offset in the input date time using:

```
String dtStr = '2014-06-19T14:44:00.000+01:00';
```

If you can, transfer the value in UTC. It will make your task easier. I.e. what happens if/when BST changes due to daylight savings time.

Comment: Brilliant :) very thorough answer that worked perfectly. With regards to the DST change, the guys on the other end swear that their system sends in UTC (even though it is undoubtedly UTC+01:00) and doesn't change for DST, so I should be alright.