# How to store the dateTime with the correct TimeStamp

Tags: datetime

I am getting the datetime value from the 3rd party. But when i try to store in the salesforce datetime field it gets stored in different TimeStamp.

For example :- 2022-08-09 14:40:00 -0400

I am getting the above value in the string format. But the correct time is  2022-08-09 10:40:00. How should i store in the salesforce datetime field with the correct timeStamp.

```
String billingDate = '2022-08-09 14:40:00 -0400';

DateTime dateTimeConvert = DateTime.valueOf(billingDate);

Integer valueOfHour = dateTimeConvert.hour();

Integer hourChange = Integer.valueOf(billingDate.substring(20, 23));

Integer changeInHour = valueOfHour + hourChange;


Opp.customDateTimeField__c = DateTime.newInstance(dateTimeConvert.year(),dateTimeConvert.month(),dateTimeConvert.day(),changeInHour,dateTimeConvert.minute(),dateTimeConvert.second());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does -0400 mean?

Comment: This is coming from the 3rd party. I guess this is the TimeZone i am not sure.

Comment: Without understanding input pattern, it is not possible to format it.

Comment: I guess this the timeZone difference they are sending. If we will subtract the same number of hour we will get the same time.

Comment: But even after i subtract and try to save in the datetime field the time gets changed.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the timezone? Looks like -0400 is trying to tell the timezone.

Comment: I have added in the above description. How should i specify the timezone?

Comment: It looks like the code you posted should work as long as the timezone offset doesn't cross the day boundary. Can you try using `.addHours(hourChange)' to the datetime field instead of doing the math beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String billingDate = '2022-08-09 14:40:00 -0400';
DateTime dateTimeConvert = DateTime.valueOfGMT(billingDate);
String testDate = dateTimeConvert.format(''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','America/New_York');
System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'**testDate***'+testDate);
```

> Debug value : 08:30:36:003 USER_DEBUG
>   [4]|ERROR|**testDate***2022-08-09 10:40:00

Comment: But when i store the above value after converting into date/time in date/time field of the opportunity it show different time. It get changed again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help: [Datetime won't save using correct time zone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41061/datetime-wont-save-using-correct-time-zone?rq=1)

You will need to format your input string to add a T between the date and time parts, and to remove the space before the timezone offset.